# Using Unittest to test my python number guessing game

Tags: python, unit-testing

This is my first Stack overflow post and I hope to make a good impression.

I am working on a number guessing game in python to get my feet wet with unittest, but I am running into a silly conundrum.

The issue is that I want to create a unittest class that tests the following things

1. Does the pregenerated number match the guessed number
2. What does the program do if you enter in a letter
3. Do you see custom errors created when an error is occurring (in the try/except block)

My github project link is here -> https://github.com/robpedersendev/python-number-guessing-game

My main.py file is below

```py
import random
import sys


def guessingGame(number, guess):  # Answer and guess was placed here so as to allow the test to insert 
                                  # its own values into the game, but that is not working
    while true:

        try:
            guess = input(
                f"Number guesser.\t\t\n {name} choose a number between "
                f"{start} and {end}. Enter guess? : ")
            guess = int(guess)
            if guess < number:
                print("\n\nThat number is a tad low\n\n")
            elif guess > number:
                print("\n\nThat number is a tad high\n\n")
            else:
                print("\n\nCongrats, you chose the right number!\n\n")
                break

        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            print("Sorry, numbers only please")
            guess = str(f"\'{guess}\' Which is an invalid character")
            continue
        except (UnboundLocalError):
            print("Sorry, numbers only please")
            continue
        finally:
            print(f"{name}, your last successful guess was {guess}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    true = True
    start = int(sys.argv[1])
    end = int(sys.argv[2])
    number = random.randrange(start, end)  # Selects the winning number
    name = input("\t\t\t\t\nHello stranger, whats your name? ")
    guessingGame()
```

My test.py file looks like

```py
import unittest
import main


class TestMain(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_input(self):
        true = True
        number = 5
        guess = 5
        result = main.guessingGame(number, guess)
        self.assertEqual(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I keep getting the error

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Robert\desktop\Side Projects\Udemy\Master python zero to Mastery\projects\python-number-guessing-game\test.py", line 10, in test_input
    result = main.guessingGame(number, guess)
  File "c:\Users\Robert\desktop\Side Projects\Udemy\Master python zero to Mastery\projects\python-number-guessing-game\main.py", line 6, in guessingGame
    while true:
NameError: name 'true' is not defined

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.375 seconds
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMMOk.png)

I know I have much to do and much to learn, but I am hoping for some helpful guidance!

UPDATE:

Ok, I figured out the problem (kinda).

The issue is within my main.py file I need to have this

```py
true = True


def guessingGame(number, guess, name='bob', start=1, end=20):
    while true:

        try:
            # guess = input(
            #     f"Number guesser.\t\t\n {name} choose a number between "
            #     f"{start} and {end}. Enter guess? : ")
            guess = int(guess)
            if guess < number:
                print("\n\nThat number is a tad low\n\n")
            elif guess > number:
                print("\n\nThat number is a tad high\n\n")
```

My test.py file

```py
import unittest
import main


class TestMain(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_input(self):
        number = 5
        guess = 5
        start = 1
        end = 20
        name = "bob"
        result = main.guessingGame(number, guess)
        self.assertEqual(guess, number)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I needed to predefine the values and comment out the first little block of code. Once I did that, my test passed!! 
Any ideas, on how to get around this piece, or was this bad design on my part?

Comment: I haven't looked super closely, but it looks like your function `main.guessingGame` doesn't actually return anything, but you are testing that it returns `True`. Hard to see how that will work. Also it doesn't look like your function ever uses the parameter `answer`.

Comment: Thank you,This was silly of me. I changed my code around. I will update with the correct structure. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: With this, I was also able to realize that everything I have under my main.py file in the 
```if __name__ == "__main__":``` section needs to also be passed in as a parameter. So I am doing that now as well.

Comment: Well, that didnt really solve anything, so back to drawing board.

Comment: Please, never use a variable `true` to assign `True` to it.  In the best case it is redundant, in the worst case the value of `true` gets changed to something that is not a true-value.  Then, `while true:` will stop working and you have a hard time figuring out why.

Comment: Ok, good point. Thank you. I will update that.

Answer (score 0):

https://book.crawfordc.com/anatomy-of-a-modern-test-file

Here’s something I wrote a while back about writing unit tests with hypothesis and pytest. 
For testing what goes wrong when you enter a letter you use the `with pytest.raises` pattern. 
Using hypothesis to generate the random numbers will also work much better than your random number generation.

(You should just make the code `while True:` and not a variable. But you would need to return false if it failed. It would probably be better as a loop. )